# Why nginx always responding with the default site even when it should now?

Tags: nginx

I recently upgraded (Debian) to nginx 1.2.1 and now it seems that nginx is always responding with the default server, even when it should not.

/etc/nginx/conf.d

```
server {
listen       80 default_server;
server_name  _;
server_name_in_redirect off;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
return 401;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/search.config

```
server {
listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
server_name  search.example.com;

location / {
   proxy_pass        http://search.example.com:8080;
   proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   }
}
```

When I try to access: http://search.example.com it will give me the 401 instead of what it is on port 8080 (which works if used directly).

Answer (score 3):

Damn, it was not loading sites-enabled because the nginx distro does not use this directory and when upgraded it replaced the nginx.conf

Comment: Also, `.config` is a rather unusual filename extension, make sure there's an actual `include sites-enabeld/*.config` line somewhere in your config. (The more typical ending would be `*.conf`.)

Comment: I know, but mc does highlights the files properly only if you use `config` and not `conf`. Considering the time wastes on this, maybe it wasn't such a good idea.

Comment: Well, you can adjust vim's config as well as change the `include` line in `nginx.conf` to look like `include sites-enabled/*.config`, of course. ;-)

Comment: My problem was caused by naming the file site.com instead of site.conf.